# How to resize partition size while the middle partition is the BIOS Boot?

Tags: linux, disk-partitioning

I used Clonezilla to restore an old system to a larger hard disk. However, when I do all my job, I found my first partition doesn't use all the disk space.

I know the method to resize the partition size by using `fdisk`, however, I noticed that there is a BIOS boot partition between the first partition and free space. Now I don't know how to deal with it.

So I want to ask how to expand my first partition to use most of my free space in this disk.

The second partition type is BIOS Boot, Contents: Unknown

[image: disk partition]

Comment: What is in `Un...` ? The parition may not be used.

Comment: @Philippe it shows Unkown . But I think it may be used to boot my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out.

I made a live boot Linux mint USB stick, then boot into the Linux Mint on USB stick. Start the GParted, then `move` the `/dev/sda2` to the end of the hard drive. Than expand the `/dev/sda1` partition to use the free space.

Then I got this:

[image: move second partition]

But be sure to back up all your data if you want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure it's used (or not used), you can :

```
# back it up
dd if=/dev/sda2 of=$HOME/sda2.dd

# wipe it
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2

# reboot
```

If reboot goes normally, that mean the partition is not used.

You can then remove sda2 and extend sda1.

Comment: If my system doesn't boot, what should I do to restore this partition?

Comment: You can use a live linux (like ubuntu) to restore, or use clonezilla to do backup/restore.

Comment: Thank you @Philippe for your advice.

Comment: Feel free to upvote if it's of some help.